# breeze - error Converting circular structure to JSON at Object.stringify (native) when altering sql view called by breeze

Tags: json, breeze

Here is my error:  Converting circular structure to JSON at Object.stringify (native)

I see clearly what is causing it:  When I change the view that Breeze is calling.  I change the view to join to a linked database and that's fine, but as soon as I call a field from the linked database, it gives this error in Visual Studio.

Can someone give a workaround or suggestion?

My breeze looks like this:

```
function BreezeFunction() {
    return breeze.EntityQuery
         .from("myview")
         .using(manager)
         .execute();
};
```

Comment: seems like the problem is coming from the html.  the ng-repeat wants UNIQUE for options so when I add the join and then add the column to the select distinct, it no longer is unique.

Comment: So that leaves me with the question:  How can I have ng-repeat allow multiple non-unique ids (with diff. values).  Is it being blocked because  I created a key for this view in my breeze mapping or does Angularjs ng-repeat inherintly not allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-repeat needs to have unique value.  if i would change my entity framework mapping to a different key that's not unique, that would also fix this, but then i end up with different logic issues.  I could also fix it by adding track by $index to the ng-repeat, but that also doesn't capture the data correctly and ultimately causes logic issues for me.  In short, angularjs is correct to demand uniqueness for ng-repeat.